# NO alert received on elastalert-test-rule or while executing the rule

Tags: elasticsearch, windows-10, elastalert

I have done setup on windows 10. Getting below output when executing elastalert-test-rule for my rule.

```
elastalert-test-rule example_rules\example_frequency.yaml --config config.yaml
Would have written the following documents to writeback index (default is elastalert_status):

elastalert_status - {'rule_name': 'Example frequency rule', 'endtime': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 19, 18, 49, 10, 397745, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'starttime': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 17, 3, 13, 10, 397745, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'matches': 4, 'hits': 4, '@timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 19, 18, 55, 56, 314841, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'time_taken': 405.48910188674927}
```

However, no alert is triggered.
Please find below contents of config.yaml and example_frequency.yaml

config.yaml

```
# This is the folder that contains the rule yaml files
# Any .yaml file will be loaded as a rule
rules_folder: example_rules

# How often ElastAlert will query Elasticsearch
# The unit can be anything from weeks to seconds
run_every:
  seconds: 5

# ElastAlert will buffer results from the most recent
# period of time, in case some log sources are not in real time
buffer_time:
  minutes: 15

# The Elasticsearch hostname for metadata writeback
# Note that every rule can have its own Elasticsearch host
es_host: 127.0.0.1

# The Elasticsearch port
es_port: 9200

# The AWS region to use. Set this when using AWS-managed elasticsearch
#aws_region: us-east-1

# The AWS profile to use. Use this if you are using an aws-cli profile.
# See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
# for details
#profile: test

# Optional URL prefix for Elasticsearch
#es_url_prefix: elasticsearch

# Connect with TLS to Elasticsearch
#use_ssl: True

# Verify TLS certificates
#verify_certs: True

# GET request with body is the default option for Elasticsearch.
# If it fails for some reason, you can pass 'GET', 'POST' or 'source'.
# See http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/connection.html?highlight=send_get_body_as#transport
# for details
#es_send_get_body_as: GET

# Option basic-auth username and password for Elasticsearch
#es_username: someusername
#es_password: somepassword

# Use SSL authentication with client certificates client_cert must be
# a pem file containing both cert and key for client
#verify_certs: True
#ca_certs: /path/to/cacert.pem
#client_cert: /path/to/client_cert.pem
#client_key: /path/to/client_key.key

# The index on es_host which is used for metadata storage
# This can be a unmapped index, but it is recommended that you run
# elastalert-create-index to set a mapping
writeback_index: elastalert_status
writeback_alias: elastalert_alerts

# If an alert fails for some reason, ElastAlert will retry
# sending the alert until this time period has elapsed
alert_time_limit:
  days: 2

# Custom logging configuration
# If you want to setup your own logging configuration to log into
# files as well or to Logstash and/or modify log levels, use
# the configuration below and adjust to your needs.
# Note: if you run ElastAlert with --verbose/--debug, the log level of
# the "elastalert" logger is changed to INFO, if not already INFO/DEBUG.
#logging:
#  version: 1
#  incremental: false
#  disable_existing_loggers: false
#  formatters:
#    logline:
#      format: '%(asctime)s %(levelname)+8s %(name)+20s %(message)s'
#
#    handlers:
#      console:
#        class: logging.StreamHandler
#        formatter: logline
#        level: DEBUG
#        stream: ext://sys.stderr
#
#      file:
#        class : logging.FileHandler
#        formatter: logline
#        level: DEBUG
#        filename: elastalert.log
#
#    loggers:
#      elastalert:
#        level: WARN
#        handlers: []
#        propagate: true
#
#      elasticsearch:
#        level: WARN
#        handlers: []
#        propagate: true
#
#      elasticsearch.trace:
#        level: WARN
#        handlers: []
#        propagate: true
#
#      '':  # root logger
#        level: WARN
#          handlers:
#            - console
#            - file
#        propagate: false
```

example_frequency.yaml

```
# Alert when the rate of events exceeds a threshold

# (Optional)
# Elasticsearch host
# es_host: elasticsearch.example.com

# (Optional)
# Elasticsearch port
# es_port: 14900

# (OptionaL) Connect with SSL to Elasticsearch
#use_ssl: True

# (Optional) basic-auth username and password for Elasticsearch
#es_username: someusername
#es_password: somepassword

# (Required)
# Rule name, must be unique
name: Example frequency rule

# (Required)
# Type of alert.
# the frequency rule type alerts when num_events events occur with timeframe time
type: frequency

# (Required)
# Index to search, wildcard supported
index: com-*

# (Required, frequency specific)
# Alert when this many documents matching the query occur within a timeframe
num_events: 1

# (Required, frequency specific)
# num_events must occur within this amount of time to trigger an alert
timeframe:
  days: 365

# (Required)
# A list of Elasticsearch filters used for find events
# These filters are joined with AND and nested in a filtered query
# For more info: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html
filter:
- term:
    "log_json.response.statusCode": "404"

# (Required)
# The alert is use when a match is found
alert:
- "email"

# (required, email specific)
# a list of email addresses to send alerts to
email:
- "username@mydomain.com"

realert:
  minutes: 0
```

What is it that i am missing to receive alerts? Neither do i see any error on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP configuration in missing, so that is why no alert is being sent.

Please try to include the `smtp_host`,`smtp_port`,`smtp_ssl` and `smtp_auth_file` in your **example_frequency.yaml**.
Refer to the document for [Email Alert](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#email)

Comment: Happy to help :)